# How can I solve storage SQL Server speed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm working on system that detects RFID tags and stores its information into a SQL Server database.

When I tried to execute my app an exception shows up:

> The data in the string or binaries will be truncated.
>   The instruction has been stopped.

I think that my problem is that the SQL Server database can't store a high number of tags in one second.

RQ: I'm using JT-928 4 Channel UHF RFID reader (it can read 300tag/second)

Mycode is:

```
no++;
//   labelCount.Text = (int.Parse(labelCount.Text) + 1).ToString(); // 更新读取次数
labelTagCount.Text = Tag_data.Count.ToString();// 更新标签计数

ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.Text = (lvTagData.Items.Count + 1).ToString();
lvi.SubItems.Add(apcData.epc);
lvi.SubItems.Add(apcData.count.ToString());
lvi.SubItems.Add(apcData.antNo.ToString());
lvi.SubItems.Add(apcData.devNo);
lvi.SubItems.Add(apcData.IP);
lvTagData.Items.Add(lvi);

missingtimer.Start();
continuscheck(apcData.epc, apcData.antNo.ToString());
```

And `continuscheck` :

```
string sqlcode1 = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[missingelemets] ([RFID],[Chanel])
                    VALUES ('" + RFID + "','" + chanel + "')";

SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UR2k_CS.Properties.Settings.StoreConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
con2.Open();

SqlCommand c1 = new SqlCommand(sqlcode1, con2);

c1.ExecuteNonQuery();// exception Instruction
con2.Close();
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `The data in the string or binaries will be truncated`, is a very common error. It typically happens when trying to insert any data in string like varchar, nvarchar, char, nchar data type column which is more than size of the column. With this in mind, are you checking the length before *trying to stuff it in the column*? If not, do so and or adjust the size of your column.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: the tags contain 24 only caracters and I used varchar(50)

Comment: The problem is the size of the column and the query itself. Quite simply the column is too short and the query is prone to SQL injection.  The *relevant* information is the table schema (ie the CREATE TABLE script), not the devices used to produce the values

Comment: Looks like you are using chinese characters (Commented code) use NVARCHAR

Comment: @aala `the tags contain 24 only caracters and I used varchar(50)` are you sure? What if one of those strings contained `'; drop table Users;--`? Or simply contained a `'` character, completely changing the meaning of the query?

Comment: @aaala and using varchar with chinese text ensures *mangled* and lost data. Use nvarchar instead, and parameterized queries. The way this query is written guarantees lost data. It's not just the string concatenation and the field type, the query uses ANSI string literals instead of Unicode literals.

Comment: I think non-Unicode chinese encodings use more than 2 bytes too, which means that a 24-character value is actually *more* than 48 bytes long, thus resulting in the truncation warning

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos but when I tried to detect only 20 tags, it works fine without any exeception.

Comment: Thanks guys, I found one of my tags with 200 caracteres I don't know how :/ but now evry things is works thank u again :D

Comment: Unless you also started using parameters instead of munging strings together this is not working correctly. Don't just go off and continue blindly like everything is rosy. The threat of sql injection is real. And when it happens it really sucks bad. Even worse when the prevention is so simple.

Comment: Ok you figured it out- but some general trouble shooting tips for next time ok? 
 Next time select the the data.  Do not insert it.  That way you can see the data you're trying to insert that's causing the error...

Comment: I 'will thanks @Zorkolot